# proc in linux , Does values modified persist after reboot?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

i want to modify 
/proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us. Will the change in file persist even after the reboot?
when does kernel read this updated value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `/proc` isn't persistent. However, most Linux distributions will read initial values from a file such as `/etc/sysctl.conf`. In this case, you can set this value in `sysctl.conf` as:

```
kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = yourvaluehere
```

See `man sysctl` for details.

Comment: i did created a file /etc/sysctl.conf above and then executed  $ service procps start. didn't see the updated value in the /proc file. Does it get refreshed?

Answer (score 3):

/proc exposes values of data structures internal to the kernel, which are stored in RAM, so no, the change is not persistent. If you want the effect of storing it persistently, you must either add the line modifying the value to an init script, so that the value is changed during boot, or you must change the default value in the kernel source. For some proc values (but probably not for this one) you could also use a kernel command line option.

Comment: Also if i modify the /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us, will it take effect immediately?

Comment: The boot loader passes a command line to the kernel with certain parameters and arguments which affect the runtime behavior of the kernel. It's not really relevant here though. I'd have to look at the source code to be 100% sure, but I'm pretty convinced that modifying sched_rt_runtime_us will take effect immediately.

Comment: when i try to edit it. it says: "sched_rt_runtime_us" E667: Fsync failed. Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: You shouldn't edit proc files with an editor, but instead read and write them using the shell (cat for reading, echo for writing). For example, if you want to set the value of sched_rt_runtime_us to 1000, you'd type in this: echo 1000 > /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us

Comment: Using Antti's syntax above didn't work for me even with sudo.  Instead I had to write it as follows: sudo sysctl -w kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us=1000000 (a million microseconds = 1 second).